# MYSQL convert and get data m/d/Y to Y/m/d

Tags: php, mysql

I import data from csv file to MYSQL database
I have a table name as `attTable` with 2 field `EMPID`, `attDate` (both String)

| EMPID | attDate |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 05/23/2023 08.30 |
| 101 | 05/23/2023 19.30 |
| 203 | 05/23/2023 08.30 |
| 203 | 05/23/2023 17.31 |

How to convert date format to `y/m/d` when select query

My mysql code as below

```sql
select empid, min(attDate) as 'TimeIN', max(attDate) as 'TimeOUT', 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, min(attDate),  max(attDate)) - 9*60 as 'OT Minutes'
from attTable
where attDate between date('2023-05-01') and date('2023-06-01') 
group by emp_id, date_format(attDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
order by emp_id
```

My problem is how to convert and get Over Time

Comment: You need to use `STR_TO_DATE(attDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H.%i')` to turn `attDate` into a meaningful DATETIME, or just `STR_TO_DATE(attDate, '%m/%d/%Y')` to turn it into a DATE.

Comment: If you do not have to import the data anymore then convert the column to date time datatype.

Comment: Please give me working code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the correct data type to use would be DATETIME you can try using this solution :

`STR_TO_DATE(attDate, '%m/%d/%Y %h.%i')`

and then if you want to convert to another format :

`DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(attDate, '%m/%d/%Y %h.%i'), 'YOUR_FORMAT')`

I recommend that you should use the correct data type for any future operations you may need to do with dates.

Comment: I updated using update query, now its perfectly working without convert `UPDATE attTable SET attDate= STR_TO_DATE(attDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') WHERE LOCATE('/', attDate); ` Please tel

Comment: I updated using update query, now its perfectly working without convert `UPDATE attTable SET attDate= STR_TO_DATE(attDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') WHERE LOCATE('/', attDate); `  now i added 3 more fields into table it is TimeIN, TimeOut, OT now i need to know how to run query update table `UPDATE attTable SET TimeIN=min(attDate), TimeIN=max(attDate), OT=
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, min(attDate),  max(attDate)) - 9*60
from attTable
where attDate between date('2023-01-01') and date('2023-06-01') 
group by emp_id, date_format(attDate, '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: You can't use GROUP clause directly in an UPDATE. Try this : ````UPDATE attTable INNER JOIN (SELECT emp_id, MIN(attDate) AS minAttDate, MAX(attDate) AS MaxAttDate, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(attDate),  MAX(attDate)) - 9*60 AS diffAttDate FROM attTable WHERE attDate BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-06-01' GROUP BY emp_id, DATE_FORMAT(attDate, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS t1 ON attTable.emp_id = t1.emp_id SET attTable.TimeIN = t1.minAttDate, attTable.TimeOUT = t1.MaxAttDate, attTable.OT = t1.diffAttDate````. It's not said that the query works, you may have to fix it depending on how the structure is made.